# RxJava: unpack object

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am using RxJava in my Android project and I'm happy about it. I'm currently using it to make all my DAO methods asynchronous and make UI listens on them.

But I have a big problem, that is, when I retrieve some data from database using `Observable<List<User>> getLists()`, I need to use `List<User>` in my ViewModels, but I cannot extract it from the observable.

I would like to know what is the common approach to solve this kind of problem ? I searched on Internet and people said it's not recommended to extract the objects, but in this case how can I use the data from database and at the same time still enable the observers listening ?

Should I create another method using AsyncTask ??

Thanks.

In my UserRepo.java

```
public Observable<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return colisDao.getUsers();
}
```

In HomeScreenViewModel.java:

```
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userRepo.getUsers(); // do not work because I need a List<User>
}
```

In HomeActivity.java:

```
UserListAdapter userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(this,
            vm.getUsers());
```

Comment: pls provide the code, it is quite unclear what should be done from the context coz the term "unpack" is opaque here

Comment: @Andrey Ilyunin In fact in my activity I have a listView, so I have to pass into the adapter a List<User>, but RxJava returns only Observable<List<User>>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Central idea of reactive extensions is to make use of events' streams observation and timely processing.

So actually, if you need to retrieve data in a straightforward way, I'd say you don't need RxJava2 at all. Still, if you want to stick to the reactive approach, the data stream should be **listened to** instead.

All RxJava2 types provide a `subscribe` method that "notifies" the source of data that's lazy by nature that here is an observer that wants to receive the data, so all the data processing flow described by use of RxJava2 operators will become alive.

The most painless approach is to change `HomeActivity's` code to this:

```
vm.getUsers()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(userListAdapter::populateWithNewDataSet);
```

, assuming that adapter will have the mentioned method that will update the UI data set using something like `notifyDataSetChanged()` (or `DiffUtil`, for instance) internally.

By doing that the data source is now observed and every time the update is emitted the UI will be repopulated with the most recent data.

P.S.: I've just demonstrated the simplest way to do the thing, but it is up to the developer where to place RxJava-related code: be it `ViewModel`, `Activity`, or even some other component. RxJava is a convenient tool to use and it can make complicated asynchronous flow simple, but the problem with RxJava arises when all the code base is dependent on it. The code base can then quickly become unmanageable, fragile and rigid if the tool was used in an improper place.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but if I got it right, that's for refreshing the adapter. I use RxJava to get rid of AsyncTask/Executors in my DAO, and it's more powerful than LiveData. I don't understand why they don't let people extract data from observables.

Comment: They actually do: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingForEach-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer- . But all the blocking unpack operation will block the calling thread as you could guess (main thread in your case, not a desirable outcome indeed). RxJava provides good means to manage asynchronous data flows in non-blocking way, and in the given example no thread will be blocked aside from those that are related to the `Schedulers.io()` thread pool designed for input\output operations

Comment: so how to get primitive type of data in non-blocking way ? What are your suggestions ?

Comment: Just like in the given example: through the subscription mechanism. This way the data will be retrieved from the database in the input\output-concerned scheduler (simply said a proxy over a thread or thread pool with a specific configuration; AFAIK `Schedulers.io()` dispatches the work to a cached thread pool) and the result will be transferred into the android's UI thread (`AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` delegates to a handler that is connected to the `Looper.getMainLooper()`), and when the data set is received - UI update will be performed.

Comment: Yes, but in populateWithNewDataSet I need to get a list of users, which I had to retrieve from the database asynchronously. How can I do that using RxJava ? I still cannot get List<User>

Comment: `subscribe` method has several overloads. The one demonstrated here needs a callback that will be invoked when the new data snapshot (in our case - `List<User>`) is emitted ( http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer- ). The example implies that `populateWithNewDataSet` is defined like this: `void populateWithNewDataSet(final List<User> snapshot)` (method reference was used for brevity).
Simply said, list of users falls into the callback provided to the `subscribe` method.

Comment: But you can do whatever you want with the data in the `subscribe` method.

Comment: Hi, maybe I was not clear, in fact I have a table User that contains several users, I need to retrieve all users from this table, then put them in a ListView, but I have to do this asynchronously and listen on table change to update UI, so I choose to use RxJava. Now the problem is that, I can only retrieve users in the type of Observable<List<User>>, but my adapter cannot take this type.

Comment: So if I take your example, I have to know how to get users in List<User> type in populateWithNewDataSet method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192619/discussion-between-andrey-ilyunin-and-brest1007).

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Adding on @AndreyIlyunin very good answer, You could also use MutableLivedata in your Viewmodel to save the List in the viewmodel as Livedata and observe changes to it in your Activity. This is suggested by Google as a way to maintain MVVM architecture. Something like:

In HomeScreenViewModel.java:

```
private final MutableLivedata<List<User>> users = new MutableLivedata<>();

public void getUsers() {
    return userRepo.getUsers()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(this::onUsers)
}

private void onUsers(List<> list){
    users.setValue(list);
}

public MutableLivedata<List<User>> getUserList(){
    return users;
}
```

In HomeActivity.java, in onCreate() add:
    vm.getUserList().observe(this,this::onUserList);

and add following methods to activity:

```
private void onUserList(List<> list){
    userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(this,list);
}
```

and then from your activity call:

```
vm.getUsers();
```

The getUsers() call is made asynchronously in the background, and you get the userList reactivly.

Comment: So I have to manage two getUsers() methods to retrieve the same data ?

Comment: You just have the getUsers() in the Viewmodel, and call it from Activity. onUsers() is a private method for your viewmodel to subscribe to the data and handle it accordingly. You can also skip the private onUsers() method and do instead subscribe(list -> users.setValue(list)) in the viewmodel. That will work too.

Comment: I know I can do it using LiveData, but I only want to achieve using RxJava